# Find points on parallel lines

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have two parallel lines, I know the coordinates of one point (the orange one) on one line, I know also the distance and I have to find the point that is on the other line, the green one.
[image]

Is it possible to calculate the coordinates of the other point?

Comment: Yes, because the red segment is perpendicular to the two lines.

Comment: @Carser How do you know?

Comment: @fleablood he said it's the distance to the other line.  The minimum length segment between the two parallel lines is perpendicular to them.

Comment: No.  Imagine you had the exact same problem but with a different pair of parallel lines.  (Another line at a different angle through (5,2) and another parallel line 4 units away.)  Obviously the answer would be different.  But we have no way of telling the difference between those two problems.  So we have no way of telling what the answer is.

Comment: You can if you know the slope of the line.  If you don't, you can't.

Comment: Yes of course, you are right you need the slope, but the red line is perpendicular...

Comment: If the line is horizontal the coordinate is (5, 6).  If the line is vertical,, the coordinate is (1,2).  If the line is at a 45 degree angle the coordiate is (5-2root(2), 2+ 2root(2)).  If the line is at some other angle, it's something else.

Comment: I think it's ambiguous when s/he wrote "the distance".  If it's distance to an arbritrary point we only know the parallel line is 4 units away or closer.  If it's the distance between the parallel lines then it is perpendicular by definition.

Comment: @fleablood Oh I completely agree.  Maybe I was making assumptions that the question is cleaner than it really is.  It seems a strange question though if the answer is "this is a just bad question" but maybe that's the case!

Comment: Yes, the line d is perpendicular. I also have the slope of the lines. When I wrote distance, I did not mean an arbitrary point, but the green one that stays on the red line which is perpendicular.

Comment: Well, you left out the *essential* information that you had the slope.  If you have the slope, yes, it certainly can be calculated.

Comment: Ok sorry for the missing info. How is possible to do that? I mean, is there a formula?

Comment: Absolutely.  You know the slope of the line and a point on the line.  So you can figure the equation of the line.  You have a point on the perpendicular so you can figure out the equation for the perpendicular.  You have the distance so you can figure the cordinates of a point a distance of 4 away.

Comment: How is the line defined? a) Point and slope, b) distance from origin and direction, c) implicit equation, d) two points ...

Answer (score 1):

From the statement “I have two parallel lines”, I am assuming that L: y = mx + c is the equation of the parallel line that passes through B with m and c known.

1. Form the circle (C) centered at A and radius = 4. That is, $C: (x – 5)^2 + (y – 2)^2 = 4^2$.
2. Combining L and C together, we get a quadratic equation in x (or in y) in the form $H: Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$.
3. Because L is tangent to C, H should have equal roots and that root is $\dfrac {-B}{2A}$.

simpler Method

Let N be the normal to L and N passes through A. The equation of N can be found.

Solving L and N, we get the required.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to know the common slope, $m=\tan \theta$, of the lines. Let the first one be$$y-mx+c=0$$ From the point $A=(5,2)$ in this line you get $c=5m-2$. Let the other line be $$y-mx+d=0$$ where $$d=c+c'=c+\frac {d}{\cos \theta}=c+4\sqrt{1+m^2}=5m-2+4\sqrt{1+m^2}$$ (see the figure below)

You get the point $B=(x,y)$ from the system
$$\begin{cases}y-mx+5m-2+4\sqrt{1+m^2}=0\\\frac{y-mx+5m-2}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}=4\end{cases}$$
where the first equation is the point $B=(x,y)$ belonging to the second line and the second equation is the formula of the distance from $B$ to the first line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the first line has direction $\vec{e}=(e_x,e_y)$ then the perpendicular has direction $\vec{n} = (-e_y,e_x)$. So starting from *A* the coordinates of *B* are

$$ (x_B,y_B)=(x_A,y_A) + d (-e_y,e_x) $$